# I want to add this Card Component dynamically when the button is pressed. So if i press the button 3 times, 3 cards must be added to the DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-component

**I want to add this Card Component dynamically when the button is pressed. So if I press the button 3 times, 3 cards must be added to the DOM. Can someone help me out why this isn't working, I'm new to react. thanks in advance. Is it because I can't use component outside the render method**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Card from './Card'

class App extends Component {

  addRobotHandler = () => {
    return (
      <Card/>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addRobotHandler}>Click me to see Robots</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a state which defined the number of counts, and render that number of cards in you render function.

```
// sample example
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cardsCount: 0
    };
  }

  addRobotHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { cardsCount: prevState.cardsCount + 1 };
    });
  };

  getCards = ()  => {
    let cards = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.cardsCount; i++) {
      cards.push(<Cards/>)
    }
    return cards;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addRobotHandler}>Click me to see Robots</button>
        {this.getCards()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering whether to study and use redux or react hooks and context API. I already have a beginner understanding of using redux. Is the React Hooks the future, Should I concentrate all my efforts on hooks now, do I need a good understanding of Redux to study Hooks and context API?

Comment: you do not need redux just now. Go through hooks and context api.. and then redux..